# Convert lua script into the instructions (opcode) equivalent to it?

Tags: c++, lua

If I had a lua script, say

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

How would I get the instructions or opcodes equivalent to it? (used for luaV_execute)

Comment: `luac -l test.lua`?

Comment: I mean to a variable, containing all opcodes.

Comment: Do you mean `lua_load`, `string.dump`, or my lbci?

Answer (score 3):

You'll barely need to do a small edit to `Lua`'s interpreter. First of all, we export the [repository](https://github.com/lua/lua)'s files:

```
~ $ svn export https://github.com/lua/lua/trunk ~/Desktop/lua_modified
~ $ cd ~/Desktop/lua_modified/
```

now, we'll need to edit the `lvm.c` file:

```
~/Desktop/lua_modified $ nano lvm.c
```

and search for `luaV_execute()` function and modify it by adding:

```
printf("%s %x %d\n",__FUNCTION__, i, GET_OPCODE(i));
```

after the first `vmfetch()` call. Let's use the `makefile` (I've edited `CC= clang-3.8` to `CC= gcc` before running `make`):

```
~/Desktop/lua_modified $ make -f makefile
```

then, after compiled the source, we are able to use our modified interpreter for testing-purposes.

```
~/Desktop/lua_modified $ ./lua # don't omit the `./` part, otherwise you'll run your original interpreter
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print("Hello, world!")
luaV_execute 400006 6
luaV_execute 4041 1
luaV_execute 1000025 37
Hello, world!
luaV_execute 26 38
>
```

Check the opcodes:

```
typedef enum {
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
name            args    description
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
OP_MOVE,/*      A B     R(A) := R(B)                                    */
OP_LOADK,/*     A Bx    R(A) := Kst(Bx)                                 */
OP_LOADBOOL,/*  A B C   R(A) := (Bool)B; if (C) pc++                    */
OP_LOADNIL,/*   A B     R(A) := ... := R(B) := nil                      */
OP_GETUPVAL,/*  A B     R(A) := UpValue[B]                              */

OP_GETGLOBAL,/* A Bx    R(A) := Gbl[Kst(Bx)]                            */
OP_GETTABLE,/*  A B C   R(A) := R(B)[RK(C)]                             */

OP_SETGLOBAL,/* A Bx    Gbl[Kst(Bx)] := R(A)                            */
OP_SETUPVAL,/*  A B     UpValue[B] := R(A)                              */
OP_SETTABLE,/*  A B C   R(A)[RK(B)] := RK(C)                            */

OP_NEWTABLE,/*  A B C   R(A) := {} (size = B,C)                         */

OP_SELF,/*      A B C   R(A+1) := R(B); R(A) := R(B)[RK(C)]             */

OP_ADD,/*       A B C   R(A) := RK(B) + RK(C)                           */
OP_SUB,/*       A B C   R(A) := RK(B) - RK(C)                           */
OP_MUL,/*       A B C   R(A) := RK(B) * RK(C)                           */
OP_DIV,/*       A B C   R(A) := RK(B) / RK(C)                           */
OP_MOD,/*       A B C   R(A) := RK(B) % RK(C)                           */
OP_POW,/*       A B C   R(A) := RK(B) ^ RK(C)                           */
OP_UNM,/*       A B     R(A) := -R(B)                                   */
OP_NOT,/*       A B     R(A) := not R(B)                                */
OP_LEN,/*       A B     R(A) := length of R(B)                          */

OP_CONCAT,/*    A B C   R(A) := R(B).. ... ..R(C)                       */

OP_JMP,/*       sBx     pc+=sBx                                 */

OP_EQ,/*        A B C   if ((RK(B) == RK(C)) ~= A) then pc++            */
OP_LT,/*        A B C   if ((RK(B) <  RK(C)) ~= A) then pc++            */
OP_LE,/*        A B C   if ((RK(B) <= RK(C)) ~= A) then pc++            */

OP_TEST,/*      A C     if not (R(A) <=> C) then pc++                   */ 
OP_TESTSET,/*   A B C   if (R(B) <=> C) then R(A) := R(B) else pc++     */ 

OP_CALL,/*      A B C   R(A), ... ,R(A+C-2) := R(A)(R(A+1), ... ,R(A+B-1)) */
OP_TAILCALL,/*  A B C   return R(A)(R(A+1), ... ,R(A+B-1))              */
OP_RETURN,/*    A B     return R(A), ... ,R(A+B-2)      (see note)      */

OP_FORLOOP,/*   A sBx   R(A)+=R(A+2);
                        if R(A) <?= R(A+1) then { pc+=sBx; R(A+3)=R(A) }*/
OP_FORPREP,/*   A sBx   R(A)-=R(A+2); pc+=sBx                           */

OP_TFORLOOP,/*  A C     R(A+3), ... ,R(A+2+C) := R(A)(R(A+1), R(A+2)); 
                        if R(A+3) ~= nil then R(A+2)=R(A+3) else pc++   */ 
OP_SETLIST,/*   A B C   R(A)[(C-1)*FPF+i] := R(A+i), 1 <= i <= B        */

OP_CLOSE,/*     A       close all variables in the stack up to (>=) R(A)*/
OP_CLOSURE,/*   A Bx    R(A) := closure(KPROTO[Bx], R(A), ... ,R(A+n))  */

OP_VARARG/*     A B     R(A), R(A+1), ..., R(A+B-1) = vararg            */
} OpCode;
```

under `lopcodes.h` header file.